# Can I make a node clickable in dash as a hyperlink?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I have this code (from [here](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/)) and it generates a network as expected:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import html
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    
    app.layout = html.Div([
        html.P("Dash Cytoscape:"),
        cyto.Cytoscape(
            id='cytoscape',
            elements=[
                {'data': {'id': 'ca', 'label': 'Canada'}}, 
                {'data': {'id': 'on', 'label': 'Ontario'}}, 
                {'data': {'id': 'qc', 'label': 'Quebec'}},
                {'data': {'source': 'ca', 'target': 'on'}}, 
                {'data': {'source': 'ca', 'target': 'qc'}}
            ],
            layout={'name': 'breadthfirst'},
            style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '1000px'}
        )
    ])
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run_server()
```

I'm just wondering, would someone know if I'm able to/how to edit this code so that I can click on a node, and it's a hyperlink to a webpage (e.g. in this case could just be the wikipedia page for each node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a callback which sets the `href` property of a `dcc.Location` component based on the clicked node:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="location"),
        cyto.Cytoscape(
            id="cytoscape",
            elements=[
                {"data": {"id": "ca", "label": "Canada"}},
                {"data": {"id": "on", "label": "Ontario"}},
                {"data": {"id": "qc", "label": "Quebec"}},
                {"data": {"source": "ca", "target": "on"}},
                {"data": {"source": "ca", "target": "qc"}},
            ],
            layout={"name": "breadthfirst"},
            style={"width": "1000px", "height": "1000px"},
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("location", "href"),
    Input("cytoscape", "tapNodeData"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def navigate_to_url(node_data):
    return f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{node_data['label']}"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it probably be better to return an `html.A` component? The `dcc.Location` component is intended for navigation _within_ the app, particularly for enabling multi-page Dash apps (see: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/location)

Comment: @JohnCollins You could return an `html.A`, but you would have to click twice. And the question asks: "would someone know if I'm able to/how to edit this code so that I can click on a node, and it's a hyperlink to a webpage". I know `dcc.Location` is mostly used for internal navigation, but I don't see a problem with the way I've used it in this answer.

Comment: Ah! Touché—good point. If indeed the behavior works like that, where the url will automatically change (but will the page refresh(?)). I had thought too to use `dcc.Location` first, but now I see indeed it may have a special advantage over `html.A` depending on the desired behavior..