# How to add arrows between interactive text labels in plotly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm creating an app which is able to connect text labels in a simple manner like it [could be done in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/text/annotations.html#using-complex-coordinates-with-annotations):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1)])
G.add_nodes_from([0, 1])
pos = {0:(0.1, 0.9), 1: (0.9, 0.5)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


annotations = {0: ax.annotate('Python', xy=pos[0], xycoords='data',
                ha="center", va="center", bbox=dict(facecolor = "blue")),
            1:ax.annotate('Programming', xy=pos[1], xycoords='data',
                ha="center", va="center", bbox=dict(facecolor = "red"))}

annotations[1].draggable()

# if you don't have networkx installed, replace G.edges with [(0,1)]
for A, B in G.edges:
    ax.annotate("", xy=pos[B], xycoords='data', xytext=pos[A], textcoords='data',
                          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="0.5",  # shrinkA=85, shrinkB=85,
                                          patchA=annotations[A],
                                          patchB=annotations[B],
                                          connectionstyle='arc3'))

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm looking for `plotly` solutions at the moment since it has a support for dynamic HTML on Jupyter Notebook and allows to run it with no JavaScript. Moreover, I want to achieve these things:

1. Functionality for accurate connection of rectangular text labels that are rectangular like it is shown in my diagram
2. Interaction 1: make labels draggable with mouse
3. Interaction 2: redraw arrows that connects text labels while dragging
4. Interaction 3: redirect to some url after text label is double clicked

The most important for me is minimal working script of connection of rectangular text labels. `matplotlib` also supports [handling events](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html). I might also like to discuss if `plotly` has a support for making all these three interactions possible to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time spent studying codes I could say that majority of things are working with some minor drawbacks.

To start with, I found it possible to implement all the functionality wanted:

- Rectangular nodes are supported
- They can be dragged
- Update of edges is working (unlike in Matplotlib annotations)
- Hyperlinks require some customisation which is not hard

#### Construction of interactive graph:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

#demo for adding urls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700675/3044825
cyto.load_extra_layouts() #dagre layout

P1 = {'data': {'id': 'p1', 'label': 'Use Bulb'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}
P2 = {'data': {'id': 'p2', 'label': 'Prod. Bulb'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}
P3 = {'data': {'id': 'p3', 'label': 'Prod. Elec', 'parent': 'm1'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}
P4 = {'data': {'id': 'p4', 'label': 'Very long line for testing'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}
P5 = {'data': {'id': 'p5', 'label': 'Prod. Glass'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}
P6 = {'data': {'id': 'p6', 'label': 'Prod. Copper'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}
P7 = {'data': {'id': 'p7', 'label': 'Prod. Fuel', 'parent': 'm1'}, 'grabbable': True, 'classes': 'process'}

E1 = {'data': {'id': 'e1', 'source': 'p7', 'target': 'p3', 'label': 'Fuel'}}
E2 = {'data': {'id': 'e2', 'source': 'p3', 'target': 'p6', 'label': 'Elec.'}}
E3 = {'data': {'id': 'e3', 'source': 'p3', 'target': 'p2', 'label': 'Elec.'}}
E4 = {'data': {'id': 'e4', 'source': 'p3', 'target': 'p5', 'label': 'Elec.'}}
E5 = {'data': {'id': 'e5', 'source': 'p3', 'target': 'p1', 'label': 'Elec.'}}
E6 = {'data': {'id': 'e6', 'source': 'p6', 'target': 'p2', 'label': 'Copper'}}
E7 = {'data': {'id': 'e7', 'source': 'p5', 'target': 'p2', 'label': 'Glass'}}
E8 = {'data': {'id': 'e8', 'source': 'p2', 'target': 'p1', 'label': 'Bulb'}}
E9 = {'data': {'id': 'e9', 'source': 'p4', 'target': 'p1', 'label': 'Waste Treatment'}}

nodes = [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]
edges = [E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7, E8, E9]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id="location"),
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape',
        layout={'name': 'dagre', 'spacingFactor': 1.15},
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '900px'},
        #stylesheet=stylesheet,
        elements=nodes+edges,
        autounselectify=True
    )])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8869) #no need for choosing a specific port if it's not in use
```

[image]

#### Customising node, edge and label style

You'll need to define `stylesheet` parameter and uncomment it in `app.layout` definition:

```
stylesheet = [
    # Group selectors
    {'selector': 'node', 'style': {'content': 'data(label)', 'font-size': 8}},
    {'selector': 'edge',
     'style': {'content': 'data(label)',
               'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
               'width': 1,
               'line-color': 'lightblue',
               'target-arrow-color': 'lightblue',
               'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
               'text-margin-x': 0,
               'font-size': 8}},

    # Class selectors
    {'selector': '.process',
     'style': {'shape': 'round-rectangle',
               'background-color': 'white',
               'border-color': 'black',
               'border-width': 1,
               'text-valign': 'center',
               'height': 40,
               'width': 75}}]
```

[image]

#### Navigation to url after node click

Based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700675/3044825), just add a callback before server run:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("location", "href"),
    Input("cytoscape", "tapNodeData"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)

def navigate_to_url(node_data):
    return f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{node_data['label']}"
```

#### Support for Jupyter Notebook

For embedding app inside Jupyter Notebook, use [JupyterDash](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash). It's simple, the only think you need is to use a different kind of app:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

#### Support for GitHub and [`nbviewer`](https://nbviewer.org/)

If you upload your app in GitHub it won't display interactive apps but you could load your GitHub link in [`nbviewer`](https://nbviewer.org/). There are two bad sides:

- It won't load unless you replace your link `https://...` of `nbviewer` with `http://...`. I'm not satisfied but this is the only workaround I could find.
- It won't load multiple apps in one notebook.

#### Support for Latex

There was no straight way in Dash Plotly to render Mathjax until release of [Dash v2.3.0](https://github.com/plotly/dash/releases/tag/v2.3.0) one month ago. It's still not supported in Dash Cytoscape which I've been using in these apps. I hope this [issue is going to be resolved](https://github.com/plotly/dash-cytoscape/issues/173) in near future.

#### Text enclosing in rectangular labels that fits it's shape.

I could find any way to do it yet as you could see in an example of node with `'Very long line for testing'`. At the moment, if text labels occurs to be long, a better design is to use circular nodes with text above.

---

I'm glad I was able to find solutions to majority of my questions and I'm still open to discuss about support for LaTeX/Mathjax, `nbviewer` and better text enclosion in labels.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do with `plotly-python` is connect two static rectangular text labels. However, doing anything interactive in Plotly that modifies any of the objects is going to requires callbacks for the most part, meaning that you will need to use `plotly-dash`.

Since you're working in a Jupyter Notebook, you could use [Jupyter-Dash](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash). If you would be interested in such a solution, I'd be happy to update my answer and provide an example.

Comment: It seems promising. I have installed Jupyter Dash and uploaded my diagrams in GitHub. At least, it is accessible via `nbviewer` and HTTP instead of HTTPS so I'm convinced that Jupyter Dash is worth looking further. Can you share an example how to connect labels and provide an example of any callback?

Comment: @mathfux sure I would be happy to- will circle back on this when I have some free time

Comment: alright, I'll try to dive more into Dash Plotly in that time

Comment: this is a tougher problem than I anticipated because tracking the coordinates of the mouse within a plotly figure isn't trivial – will update this answer when I figure it out though

Comment: After my long researches I came with nice answers. I'm satisfied with design I was able to achieve at the moment since I know that trying to implement networks in Dash with no Cytoscape is really tricky. Thanks for assistance anyways :)